# Protocols.SoapException : File Cannot be found and I put the path

Tags: c#, openxml

How can i go about something like this. I am getting this Error

[image: Error message]

I am trying to do something like a Document Path and its not getting it very correctly.
My code looks like this :

```
public bool PrintOnMicrosoftWord(string ID, string docPath)
{
    string constring = "Data Source=DLX;Initial Catalog=K2;User ID=K2_User; Password=K2_User;";
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring))
    {
        con.Open();
        string sqlQuery = "select * from [K2].[dbo].[E-MemoFinalPDF] where id = @id";
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, con))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", ID);
            using (SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                try
                {
                    if (rd.Read())
                    {
                        string to_Field = rd["To_Field"].ToString();
                        string from_field = rd["From_Field"].ToString();
                        string copy_field = rd["copy_field"].ToString();
                        string date_field = rd["date_field"].ToString();
                        string subject_field = rd["Subject"].ToString();
                        string manname1 = rd["ManName1"].ToString();
                        string manname2 = rd["ManName2"].ToString();
                        string manname3 = rd["ManName3"].ToString();
                        string manname4 = rd["ManName4"].ToString();
                        string manname5 = rd["ManName5"].ToString();
                        string manname10 = rd["ManName10"].ToString();
                        string ManDesg1 = rd["ManDesg1"].ToString();
                        string ManDesg2 = rd["ManDesg2"].ToString();
                        string ManDesg3 = rd["ManDesg3"].ToString();
                        string ManDesg4 = rd["ManDesg4"].ToString();
                        string ManDesg5 = rd["ManDesg5"].ToString();
                        string ManDesg10 = rd["ManDesg10"].ToString();
                        string approval1 = rd["Approval1"].ToString();
                        string approval2 = rd["Approval2"].ToString();
                        string approval3 = rd["Approval3"].ToString();
                        string approval4 = rd["Approval4"].ToString();
                        string approval5 = rd["Approval5"].ToString();
                        string approval10 = rd["Approval10"].ToString();

                        //print information on Docx Document

                        using (WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(docPath, true))
                        {
                            MainDocumentPart mainPart = doc.MainDocumentPart;

                            SdtElement to_block = mainPart.Document.Body.Descendants<SdtElement>().Where(r => r.SdtProperties.GetFirstChild<Tag>().Val == "To").Single();
                            SdtElement from_block = mainPart.Document.Body.Descendants<SdtElement>().Where(r => r.SdtProperties.GetFirstChild<Tag>().Val == "From").Single();
                            SdtElement copy_block = mainPart.Document.Body.Descendants<SdtElement>().Where(r => r.SdtProperties.GetFirstChild<Tag>().Val == "Copy").Single();
                            SdtElement date_block = mainPart.Document.Body.Descendants<SdtElement>().Where(r => r.SdtProperties.GetFirstChild<Tag>().Val == "Date").Single();
                            SdtElement subject_block = mainPart.Document.Body.Descendants<SdtElement>().Where(r => r.SdtProperties.GetFirstChild<Tag>().Val == "Subject").Single();

                            SdtElement manname1_block = mainPart.Document.Body.Descendants<SdtElement>().Where(r => r.SdtProperties.GetFirstChild<Tag>().Val == "ManName1").Single();
                            SdtElement manname2_block = mainPart.Document.Body.Descendants<SdtElement>().Where(r => r.SdtProperties.GetFirstChild<Tag>().Val == "ManName2").Single();
                            SdtElement manname3_block = mainPart.Document.Body.Descendants<SdtElement>().Where(r => r.SdtProperties.GetFirstChild<Tag>().Val == "ManName3").Single();
                            SdtElement manname4_block = mainPart.Document.Body.Descendants<SdtElement>().Where(r => r.SdtProperties.GetFirstChild<Tag>().Val == "ManName4").Single();
                            SdtElement manname5_block = mainPart.Document.Body.Descendants<SdtElement>().Where(r => r.SdtProperties.GetFirstChild<Tag>().Val == "ManName5").Single();
                            SdtElement manname10_block = mainPart.Document.Body.Descendants<SdtElement>().Where(r => r.SdtProperties.GetFirstChild<Tag>().Val == "ManName10").Single();

                            SdtElement mandesg1_block = mainPart.Document.Body.Descendants<SdtElement>().Where(r => r.SdtProperties.GetFirstChild<Tag>().Val == "ManDesg1").Single();
                            SdtElement mandesg2_block = mainPart.Document.Body.Descendants<SdtElement>().Where(r => r.SdtProperties.GetFirstChild<Tag>().Val == "ManDesg2").Single();
                            SdtElement mandesg3_block = mainPart.Document.Body.Descendants<SdtElement>().Where(r => r.SdtProperties.GetFirstChild<Tag>().Val == "ManDesg3").Single();
                            SdtElement mandesg4_block = mainPart.Document.Body.Descendants<SdtElement>().Where(r => r.SdtProperties.GetFirstChild<Tag>().Val == "ManDesg4").Single();
                            SdtElement mandesg5_block = mainPart.Document.Body.Descendants<SdtElement>().Where(r => r.SdtProperties.GetFirstChild<Tag>().Val == "ManDesg5").Single();
                            SdtElement mandesg10_block = mainPart.Document.Body.Descendants<SdtElement>().Where(r => r.SdtProperties.GetFirstChild<Tag>().Val == "ManName10").Single();

                            SdtElement approval1_block = mainPart.Document.Body.Descendants<SdtElement>().Where(r => r.SdtProperties.GetFirstChild<Tag>().Val == "Approval1").Single();
                            SdtElement approval2_block = mainPart.Document.Body.Descendants<SdtElement>().Where(r => r.SdtProperties.GetFirstChild<Tag>().Val == "Approval2").Single();
                            SdtElement approval3_block = mainPart.Document.Body.Descendants<SdtElement>().Where(r => r.SdtProperties.GetFirstChild<Tag>().Val == "Approval3").Single();
                            SdtElement approval4_block = mainPart.Document.Body.Descendants<SdtElement>().Where(r => r.SdtProperties.GetFirstChild<Tag>().Val == "Approval4").Single();
                            SdtElement approval5_block = mainPart.Document.Body.Descendants<SdtElement>().Where(r => r.SdtProperties.GetFirstChild<Tag>().Val == "Approval5").Single();
                            SdtElement approval10_block = mainPart.Document.Body.Descendants<SdtElement>().Where(r => r.SdtProperties.GetFirstChild<Tag>().Val == "Approval10").Single();


                            Text to = to_block.Descendants<Text>().Single();
                            Text from = from_block.Descendants<Text>().Single();
                            Text copy = copy_block.Descendants<Text>().Single();
                            Text date = date_block.Descendants<Text>().Single();
                            Text subject = subject_block.Descendants<Text>().Single();

                            Text manager1 = manname1_block.Descendants<Text>().Single();
                            Text manager2 = manname2_block.Descendants<Text>().Single();
                            Text manager3 = manname3_block.Descendants<Text>().Single();
                            Text manager4 = manname4_block.Descendants<Text>().Single();
                            Text manager5 = manname5_block.Descendants<Text>().Single();
                            Text manager10 = manname10_block.Descendants<Text>().Single();

                            Text mandesg1 = mandesg1_block.Descendants<Text>().Single();
                            Text mandesg2 = mandesg2_block.Descendants<Text>().Single();
                            Text mandesg3 = mandesg3_block.Descendants<Text>().Single();
                            Text mandesg4 = mandesg4_block.Descendants<Text>().Single();
                            Text mandesg5 = mandesg5_block.Descendants<Text>().Single();
                            Text mandesg10 = mandesg10_block.Descendants<Text>().Single();

                            Text appr1 = approval1_block.Descendants<Text>().Single();
                            Text appr2 = approval2_block.Descendants<Text>().Single();
                            Text appr3 = approval3_block.Descendants<Text>().Single();
                            Text appr4 = approval4_block.Descendants<Text>().Single();
                            Text appr5 = approval5_block.Descendants<Text>().Single();
                            Text appr10 = approval10_block.Descendants<Text>().Single();


                            to.Text = to_Field;
                            from.Text = from_field;
                            copy.Text = to_Field;
                            date.Text = date_field;
                            subject.Text = subject_field;

                            manager1.Text = manname1;
                            manager2.Text = manname2;
                            manager3.Text = manname3;
                            manager4.Text = manname4;
                            manager5.Text = manname5;

                            mandesg1.Text = ManDesg1;
                            mandesg2.Text = ManDesg2;
                            mandesg3.Text = ManDesg3;
                            mandesg4.Text = ManDesg4;
                            mandesg5.Text = ManDesg5;

                            appr1.Text = approval1;
                            appr2.Text = approval2;
                            appr3.Text = approval3;
                            appr4.Text = approval4;
                            appr5.Text = approval5;

                            mainPart.Document.Save();
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }
            }
        }

    }
    return true;
}
```

Its not able to find Document. I am wondering why? Do I appear to be missing something? This works fine on my iisexpress from my visual studio, it works, but should I want to point it to the path to be referenced or used directly, It tells me it cannot find the document.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing an incorrect path to the `WordprocessingDocument.Open(string, bool)` method, which throws a `FileNotFoundException` because there is no document with that path at least in that runtime environment. Therefore, you need to find out how you have to specify paths of different kinds of content (e.g., content used by the app; public, static resources like CSS, JavaScript, and image files) residing on the webserver.

In ASP.NET Core, for example, you would use the `ContentRootPath` and `WebRootPath` properties of the `IWebHostEnvironment` interface to find relevant root paths.

So, say your document is located within some folder below the content root. Assuming `_env` is an instance of `IWebHostEnvironment`, the following code example shows how you would specify an absolute path to be passed to the `WordprocessingDocument.Open(string, bool)` method.

```cs
string relativeDocPath = "path/relative/to/content/root/document.docx";
string absoluteDocPath = Path.Combine(_env.ContentRootPath, relativeDocPath);
```